# Python Pandas values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with numbers. I want to add another column, which shows the percentage to the max value.

amount   percentage

10  -         100%

3    -        30%

3     -       30%

4      -      40%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['pct'] = 100 * df['value'] / df['value'].max()
```

Comment: This would give fraction values. Not percentage values.

Answer (score 2):

For the below `df`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col':[10,3,4,5]
})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col     
0   10  
1    3   
2    4   
3    5
```

You would need:

```
df['pr'] = (df['col']/df['col'].max() *100).astype(int).map(str) + ' %'
```

Output:

```
   col     pr
0   10  100 %
1    3   30 %
2    4   40 %
3    5   50 %
```